# Rotary Switch terminology

Tags: switches

I am buying a rotary switch, and I have found these terms:

```
2 x Off/(On)
```

and

```
2 x Off/On
```

Could you please explain me the difference?

**edit:**
example of a switch with `Off/(On)` specification
[image]
([originally from this page](http://www.conradelektronik.dk/?websale8=conrad-dk&pi=704706&rdeocl=1&rdetpl=productpage&rdebox=box1))

Comment: There probably isn't one, but no way to know without links to the datasheets.

Comment: Please post links to datasheets where you have seen these terms.

Comment: It is in danish: https://www.conradelektronik.dk/websale8/?Ctx=%7bver%2f8%2fver%7d%7bst%2f3eb%2fst%7d%7bcmd%2f1%2fcmd%7d%7bm%2fwebsale%2fm%7d%7bs%2fconrad-dk%2fs%7d%7bl%2f02-aa%2fl%7d%7bmi%2fSHOP_AREA_17383_0216250%2fmi%7d%7bpi%2f704675%2fpi%7d%7bbi%2f4%2fbi%7d%7bmd5%2f6c3eced2ddf8f406a0bbc52167c25b1a%2fmd5%7d

Comment: And: http://www.conradelektronik.dk/?websale8=conrad-dk&pi=704706&rdeocl=1&rdetpl=productpage&rdebox=box1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually positions in parenthesis are momentary positions.

So a switch that is Off/(On) is a single throw switch that is momentary switch.  It will not stay in the on position, but will spring back to the off position.  A switch that is Off/On will stay in either position.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the first one's a SPDT spring-loaded single-side-stable OFF-momentary ON switch, while the second one is just a vanilla DPST ON-OFF switch.